# Is it possible to consume an external API using Microstrategy?

Tags: report, reporting, microstrategy

I am trying to see if an external API can be consumed from Microstrategy. I am new to this and so far I have seen a connector on Microstrategy that allows you to bring data from an URL, but when things get more complex like passing a specific header parameter, then the connector is not useful.

Also going through the documentation I have seen they have internal APIs that any external application can consume to create reports outside of Microstrategy or to join data hosted on Microstrategy.

Their documentation for internal APIs is this one, but I am sure the other way around is possible, I just need a direction or an example to understand.

https://www.microstrategy.com/en/support/support-videos/how-to-use-the-rest-api-in-library

Answer (score 1):

You can use XQuery for this. You can look there;
https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/AdvancedReportingGuide/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/Using_XQuery_to_retrieve_data_from_a_web_service.htm#freeform_sql_4027597040_1133899
https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/How-to-Create-a-Report-That-Dynamically-Retrieves-Data-From-a-Parameterized-Web-Service?language=en_US

I've samples for that, we can talk about that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the external data function provided by rest api.

> The Push Data API, which belongs to the Dataset API family, lets you
> make external data easily available for analysis in MicroStrategy. You
> use REST APIs to create and modify datasets using external data
> uploaded directly to the Intelligence Server.
>
> By providing a simpler, quicker way to get data out and add data back
> in, the Push Data API makes it easier to use MicroStrategy as a
> high-performance data storage and retrieval mechanism and supports
> predictive workflow by machine learning, artificial intelligence, and
> data scientist teams. The ability to make external data easily
> available extends MicroStrategy's reach to new and complex data
> sources where code, rather than end-users, manages the data
> modeling/mapping flow. The Push Data API supports close integration
> with the ecosystem of third-party ETL tools because it allows them to
> push data directly into MicroStrategy while allowing the most optimal
> utilization of MicroStrategy's cube capabilities. The Push Data API
> provides these tools, whether they are analyst or IT-oriented, with
> the option to create and update datasets on the MicroStrategy
> Intelligence Server without requiring an intermediate step of pushing
> the data into a warehouse.

You can first make sure the data is ready in your local environment and then push it to the MSTR server as the instruction.

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/RESTSDK/Content/topics/REST_API/REST_API_PushDataAPI_MakingExternalDataAvailable.htm